# O_TRUNC ignored when writing to the /proc filesystem

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, procfs, sysctl

Trying to get rid of Ubuntu's `apport` by clearing `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` using
`sh -c ': > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'` does not work.

It looks like the `O_TRUNC` flag is ignored when writing to the `/proc` filesystem:

```
echo nonsense >| /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
strace sh -c ': > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern  # do not call apport'
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
close(3)                                = 0

cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
nonsense
```

I get an empty file when doing this in regular filesystems instead of the `/proc` filesystem.

**Is that a kernel bug or a feature**, perhaps even a documented one?

**Edit:** Clearing this setting through `sysctl` does not work:

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=""
sysctl: malformed setting "kernel.core_pattern="
```

It seems the sysctl program is unable to clear any kernel parameters while `man core` explicitly describes that an empty value is used to disable the mechanism.

Yes, `echo >| /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` works instead, but the object of this question is to find out whether this is a kernel bug, not to find a workaround.

Comment: Try writing a zero length buffer to the file. If that doesn't work, try writing just a single newline character.

Comment: BTW, the usual method of modifying `/proc/sys/` files is by using the `sysctl` command. E.g. `sudo sysctl kernel.core_pattern=`.

Comment: Files on /proc are a bit weird anyway because their content is generated dynamically and their sizes are listed as 0.

Comment: @IanAbbott, just edited the question to show that `sysctl` does not work here. But this is not the object of the question anyway.

Comment: It could be argued that since the file has a size of 0 (as indicated by `stat`) then it cannot be truncated.

Comment: @IanAbbott, good point. But I'd like some source that is more than an argument for that to become the accepted answer of the question. Do you think I should ask a new question for that, e.g. "Can non-empty virtual files that appear as zero-length still be truncated" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `O_TRUNC` flag of the `open*` family of syscalls merely updates the size of the inode associated with the opened file. This change is performed right after finding the inode and before finalizing the [`struct file`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/fs.h#L944) that is then used by the kernel for any actual operation on the opened file. Truncation is performed before the call to any `->open()` [`file_operations`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/locking.html#file-operations) handler implemented by whichever kernel module/driver/subsystem (like for example the sysctl subsystem) and is therefore transparent to the handler.

In other words, the `file_operations` handlers of the virtual [sysctl files](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/index.html#introduction) (e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/*`) merely see a file with a 0 (zero) size (`->i_size` field of [`struct inode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/fs.h#L636)), they do not know whether this was the result of a truncation or a "normal" `open`, nor they should need such information.

Since sysctl files (just as the near totality of procfs files) do not really bother tracking sizes for understandable reasons, **their functionality is only implemented in terms of `read` and `write` system calls** (which also do not update the size in any way).

Indeed, using `: > PATH` will merely do `open` + `close`, while a simple `echo > PATH` will `write` a newline character after opening, thus you observe two different outcomes. You would observe the same behavior as `: > PATH` using `truncate -s 0 PATH`, though this time the truncation is done explicitly after opening through [`ftruncate`](https://manned.org/ftruncate.2) (at least on my system).

> `man core` explicitly describes that an empty value is used to disable the mechanism
>
> [...]
>
> Is that a kernel bug or a feature, perhaps even a documented one?

Human readable/writable files under procfs are usually designed to work in a line-oriented fashion, so I would assume that the term "empty" here simply means that the value of the option is empty as a result of writing an empty line to the file. If anything, I would call this an undocumented feature rather than a bug.

---

Here's some example traces on my system:

```
root@xxx:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
root@xxx:~# strace -f -e openat,write,close,dup2 sh -c ': > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(1)                                = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
...
+++ exited with 0 +++
root@xxx:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
root@xxx:~#
```

```
root@xxx:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
root@xxx:~# strace -f -e openat,write,close,dup2 sh -c 'echo > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(1)                                = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
...
+++ exited with 0 +++
root@xxx:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

root@xxx:~#
```

If you want to take a look at the actual implementation of `open`/`read`/`write`/`close` for sysfs files you can check [`/kernel/sysctl.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/proc/proc_sysctl.c#L610). There are different tables present for different sysctl facilities e.g. [`kernel`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L1655), [`vm`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L2647), etc.

Comment: So I conclude it's a documentation bug in `man core`: Empty means an empty line, not an empty file. Great work, btw.